# Magento UI Library to use or not to use?

Tags: magento2, ui-library

Is anyone using Magento 2's built in UI Library?

I usually like to keep things inline with the framework, so I try to use the tools provided and follow the best practices set by the framework.  But the new UI Library is ugly and over complicated with very little documentation.  I really don't want to use it.

I'm just wondering if it's just me that doesn't like it and what everyone else is doing with regards theming in Mage 2?

Answer (score 1):

I use it whenever applicable, it can be a huge time saver and it's always good to be consistent with the framework. I'm not sure if you're saying the code is ugly or that you don't like the base styling, either way I'd suggest trying to learn and use it in earnest before abandoning. In my opinion, it's actually one of the better documented areas, take a look at `pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/index.html` in your installation. The main things you need to know is how the file structure works and how to use Less features such as mixins and variables.

Comment: I meant the code when I said it's ugly, but I don't like the structure either.  Like using a mobile and a desktop stylesheet that essentially import the same LESS files but with a "mobile" and "common" flag to determine which styles to import.  I've read the documentation that ships with the installation, but for me it doesn't explain in enough detail what everything is doing, which forces me to have to go reading through all the LESS files manually to figure it out.

Comment: For instance the dropdown UI, I created one and applied the markup and styles as per the docs, except I wanted my dropdown to be a div as opposed to a list.  It didn't work and after digging through the LESS I discovered it only works with lists.  I'd drop it in favor of bootstrap in a heartbeat, I'm just concerned that any extensions might rely heavily on the built in UI Library...

Answer (score 0):

I published on this page below if you want to consult.

https://magebr.github.io/Magento-2-UI-library/index.html

Or you can use this route in your project:

**Nginx**

> yourcustomstore.com/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/index.html

**Apache**

> yourcustomstore.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/index.html